# Pandas : remove duplicated rows using mode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using a `pandas.Dataframe`, how should I remove duplicated (based on multiple columns) rows using the mode of another column ?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "col_1": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "col_2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "col_3": [5, 5, 0, 1, 8, 8, 0, 1],
        "another_column": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    }
)

# the following line shows the correct answer but doesn't return original dataframe
# with only the two unique rows
print(df.groupby(by=["col_1", "col_2"])["col_3"].agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and compare original column `col_3` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.groupby(by=["col_1", "col_2"])["col_3"].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
df1 = df[df['col_3'].eq(s)]
print (df1)
   col_1  col_2  col_3  another_column
0      0      1      5               0
1      0      1      5               0
4      1      2      8               0
5      1      2      8               0
```

If need first row per groups:

```
s = df.groupby(by=["col_1", "col_2"])["col_3"].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
df1 = df[df['col_3'].eq(s)].drop_duplicates(["col_1", "col_2"])
print (df1)
   col_1  col_2  col_3  another_column
0      0      1      5               0
4      1      2      8               0
```

Comment: I'd use `.item()` instead of `[0]` to make it clear there's only ever one value

Comment: @timgeb - hmmm, `mode` should return 2 values, then `item` failed.

Comment: you're correct, I didn't remember that `mode` can return multiple values when there's no single most common value